# CPQ - twin fields not working for certain profiles due to security setting

Tags: apex, security, cpq

We are building a twin field in quote and order in the hope that the field value can be automatically copied into order. This is working for other profiles but not sales user since they don't have edit access on order.

I complete understand this behaviour but I can't go into cpq managed code and change that into without sharing. But I kind of don't want to duplicate that logic in our own trigger.

Is there a solution to this issue without having to duplicate the logic?

Comment: Can you post your code to visualize the issue